# warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int *' but the argument has type 'unsigned char *' [-Wformat]

Tags: c++

When compiling C ++ code in Visual Studio 2017, I get the following output information:

> ```
> main.cpp:139:34: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int *' but the argument has type 'unsigned char *' [-Wformat]
>                                 sscanf(&item[2 * i], "%02X", &my1ch);
>                                                       ~~~~   ^~~~~~
>                                                       %2s
> main.cpp:154:34: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int *' but the argument has type 'unsigned char *' [-Wformat]
>                                 sscanf(&item[2 * i], "%02X", &my1ch);
>                                                       ~~~~   ^~~~~~
>                                                       %2s
> main.cpp:168:34: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int *' but the argument has type 'unsigned char *' [-Wformat]
>                                 sscanf(&item[2 * i], "%02X", &my1ch);
>                                                       ~~~~   ^~~~~~
>                                                       %2s
> main.cpp:191:40: warning: flag '0' results in undefined behavior with 's' conversion specifier [-Wformat]
>                 printf("[ERROR] START/END IsGreater %064s \n", maxKey.GetBase16().c_str());
>                                                     ~^~~~
> main.cpp:275:26: warning: flag '0' results in undefined behavior with 's' conversion specifier [-Wformat]
>                         printf("[load] start=%064s \n", bc->ksStart.GetBase16().c_str());
>                                              ~^~~~
> main.cpp:276:26: warning: flag '0' results in undefined behavior with 's' conversion specifier [-Wformat]
>                         printf("[load]  next=%064s \n", bc->ksNext.GetBase16().c_str());
>                                              ~^~~~
> main.cpp:277:26: warning: flag '0' results in undefined behavior with 's' conversion specifier [-Wformat]
>                         printf("[load]   end=%064s \n", bc->ksFinish.GetBase16().c_str());
>                                              ~^~~~
> main.cpp:394:30: warning: flag '0' results in undefined behavior with 's' conversion specifier [-Wformat]
>   fprintf(f, "Priv (HEX): 0x%064s\n", pAddrHex.c_str());
>                             ~^~~~
> main.cpp:419:20: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
>   lambda.SetBase16("5363ad4cc05c30e0a5261c028812645a122e22ea20816678df02967c1b23bd72");
>                    ^
> main.cpp:420:21: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
>   lambda2.SetBase16("ac9c52b33fa3cf1f5ad9e3fd77ed9ba4a880b9fc8ec739c2e0cfc810b51283ce");
>                     ^
> main.cpp:572:20: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *' [-Wwritable-strings]
>   maxKey.SetBase16("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364140");
>                    ^
> main.cpp:782:29: warning: flag '0' results in undefined behavior with 's' conversion specifier [-Wformat]
>   printf("[keyspace] start=%064s\n", bc->ksStart.GetBase16().c_str());
>                            ~^~~~
> main.cpp:783:29: warning: flag '0' results in undefined behavior with 's' conversion specifier [-Wformat]
>   printf("[keyspace]   end=%064s\n", bc->ksFinish.GetBase16().c_str());
> ```

So how should it look right?

Link to file content is here: https://github.com/JeanLucPons/VanitySearch/blob/master/main.cpp

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].  When the link to the code breaks so does the usefulness of the question to future readers.

Comment: Please do not link to code. Post the relevant code here. Also, pick a tag. C and C++ are different.

Comment: OK. Sorry... wait a second

Comment: Which of those warnings are unclear? They point to the exact lines that are causing the warnings. Do you have a more specific question than "what is wrong with my code?"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [sscanf(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)

> Conversions
>
> The following type modifier characters can appear in a conversion
>   specification:
>
> h
>
> Indicates that the conversion will be one of d, i, o,
>   u, x, X, or n and the next pointer is a pointer to a short int or
>   unsigned short int (rather than int).
>
> hh
>
> As for h, but the next pointer is a pointer to a signed char or
>   unsigned char.
>
> ...

=> you need `"%02hhX"` rather than `"%02X"` if you want to `sscanf` into an `unsigned char`.